# Could not parse as each: "${e : #fields.errors('userName')}"

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to validate my form using hibernate validator. But while running my form I am getting a error

```
Could not parse as each: "${e : fields.errors('userName')}" (template: "home" - line 28, col 14)
```

This is my home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        
            <form th:action="@{/process}" method="post" th:object="${loginData}">
            
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Username</label>
                
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                name="userName"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                th:value="${loginData.userName}"
                th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('userName')?'is-invalid':''}"
                >
                <div th:each="${e : #fields.errors('userName')}" th:text="${e}" class="invalid-feedback"></div> 
                
              </div>
              
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Email</label>
                
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="email"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
                th:value="${loginData.email}"
                  th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')?'is-invalid':''}"
                >
                 <div th:each="${e:#fields.errors('email')}" th:text="${e}" class="invalid-feedback"></div> 
              </div>
              
              <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                class="form-check-input" 
                id="exampleCheck1">
                
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
              
              </div>
              
              <button 
              type="submit" 
              class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              
            </form>
                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In this file I have used thymeleaf.

This is my entity class where I have used:

```
package org.springboot.entities;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class LoginData {

    @NotBlank(message = "The textbox cannot be blank")
    @Size(min = 3, max= 15, message = "The field should be of length between 3-15")
    private String userName;

    @NotBlank(message = "The textbox cannot be blank")
    
    private String email;
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LoginData [userName=" + userName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
    
}
```

My Home controller:

```
package org.springboot.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springboot.entities.LoginData;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String viewForm(Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("loginData", new LoginData());
        
        return "home";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/process")
    public String process
    (@Valid @ModelAttribute("loginData") LoginData loginData, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result);
            return "home";
        }
        System.out.println(loginData);
        return "success";
    }
    
}
```

Please guide me through this error. I actually want to show the the error message on my login form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's incorrect syntax for a th:each... it should be `th:each="e : ${#fields.errors('userName')}"`

Comment: Please help me with right syntax

Comment: I just did... in my original comment.